# Submit FireMonkey Project to Mac App Store, Icon Issue

Tags: xcode, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe3

From the Doc, it mentioned the package needs to include two .icns files, one for Retina, another one for non-Retina, but it didn't explain what will be the Filenames for these two .icns files, I checked other apps, it seems they include one .icns file only, so what should I do?

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Mac_OS_X_Application_Development#Icons_for_Your_OS_X_Apps

Comment: But that link doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Presumably the .icns files can be named whatever you want them to be, if Apple doesn't specifically tell you what names to use in their documentation. This would make perfect sense, as apps are placed in their own bundles for download, so filenames couldn't clash. This isn't a Delphi question in any case, as the icon file name requirements would be from the Apple documentation and have nothing to do with Delphi.

Comment: maybe you are correct, but the doc said one icns file for retina, another file for non-retina, so filename is an issue, @2x or something else? I don't know..

Comment: Um, no. Filename is not the issue. **Image format** is the issue (one image for retina, one for non-retina). "To submit your app to the Mac App Store, your package needs to include two .icns files:  512x512 pixels (for non-Retina displays), 1024x1024 pixels (for Retina displays)". There is NO mention of filename requirements. Again, **Apple** gives you this information in **their** documentation; it's not a Delphi question. Have you checked the Apple Developer Site for this information?

Comment: Also, read the accepted answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596776/create-10241024-icns, which was linked from the documentation you linked originally. It tells you that the 1024x1024 file should be named `512x512@2x.png` (in the second comment to that answer).

Comment: I actually checked other apps downloaded from app store, they only contain one icns file, and the name is not 512x512@2x.png. This is confusing.. apple's doc is for xcode users, so..

Comment: Will you *please* read the other SO question (including all of the answers to it)? The information is right there. (It's one .icns file that contains at least two images, one of each size. This is just like Windows .ico files, which can contain one or more icon images that support multiple resolutions.)